# Size of toolbar icons

Tags: android, icons, android-toolbar

I noticed that all my toolbar icons are somehow larger that others apps like Gmail, Telegram, etc.

Gmail:

[image]

My app:
[image]

I downloaded icons in 4 sizes (hdpi-mdpi-xhdpi-xxhdpi) from [materialdesignicons.com](http://materialdesignicons.com) and stored in correct drawable folder.

How can I make them look like the ones in Gmail?

Comment: create custom bar layout and set icon size

Comment: can you please upload your image file used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own custom icons according to the specifications specified in the following link :-

https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html